# CSS not working for IE 11 and saffari

Tags: css, cross-browser

My CSS style not working properly for IE 11 and Safari browsers. I searched every possible place to find an answer but failed.   a lot of people talking about cross-browser CSS problem but no one did a working example and show how it's done properly.  so if you guys know please help me to overcome this issue.

this is a part of my CSS I found not working for IE and safari

```
         <style>   .lap_drop_dwn:before {
                content:"";
                position: absolute;
                right: 31px;
                top: -10px;
                width: 0;
                height: 0;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
                border-color: transparent transparent rgb(0,0,0,0.5) transparent; 
            } 


            .drop_dwn_items { 
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                height: 50px; 
                background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.5);
                text-decoration: none;
                line-height: 50px;
                font-size: 22px; 
                color: #fff;
                padding: 0 20px;
                text-align: center;
            }
 </style>
```

this is a part I found, but my CSS file is quite large so there could be many so hard to find manually.  it would be better if there is some script which automatically fixes those errors according to particular browser needs.

Comment: can you share a full code including HTML so we can reproduce this? also it would be good to add screeshot to show the different behaviors

Comment: problem is i dont want that kind of a solution , what do you mean by you can reproduce it ?  what happen when i developing another website in future ? do i have to ask a question here again ? i need a dirct solution like to use HTML5  website on IE6  there is a code to add  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

Comment: well, there is no direct generic solution. I cannot give a magic trick that make ALL your code works fine on all the browsers, if we know this kind of magic no one will never face any issue. We can help you with your particular issue if you show us the problem and if we are able to reproduce it,

Comment: The good news is that yes, there is a solvable issue in even the small part of the CSS you have chosen to show us. IE11 at least (can't speak for Safari) does not recognise the newer 4-value `rgb` function yet, so you will have to write `rgba` explicitly for those instances. Of course `rgba` still works for all other browsers too.

Comment: ok  @TemaniAfif   thanks for the reply what do you mean by we ? are you guys a developer team ? can i contact you if i wanna reproduce future css files ?

Comment: thanks  @MrLister  i can change rgb to rgba  but that  .lap_drop_dwn:before  selector is not working it supposed to create a triangle with boarders but it makes a rectangle in IE11.   is there any JavaScript cdn created to fix all of these css ?

Comment: We = everyone here on SO, and I am one person :) ... if you wanna contact me for something feel free to check my profile but we [SO users] need more information within the question in order to be able to help you. We need to see the HTML code as we need to see something working in order to check the behavior and help you

Comment: I put your css in [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stq8jjtn/1/), and it works the same way in all browsers with rgb changed to rgba. There is not much else I can say.